# laravel 4 Auth::attempt allways returns true?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, laravel-4

Earlier today I had the exact same problem with Auth::attempt always retuning false. I realized that Auth checks for a hashed password, so by doing so I was able to get it to return true, but now it always does. Even if I type asdadfasdfaf in my form, the if statement loads the page. Any suggestions?

Controller:

```
class userController extends \BaseController 
{


public function login()
{


      $user = array(
        'username'  => Input::get('username'),
        'password'  => Input::get('password') 
    );


    if(Auth::attempt($user)) 
    {
        return Redirect::route('home');
    }

    else
    {
        return View::make('login');

    }




}
}
```

Form

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'home' )) }}
    {{ Form::label('username', 'Username: ') }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}
        </br>
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password: ') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
        </br>
{{ Form::submit() }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

The Routes file:

```
Route::post('home', 'userController@login');
```

No matter what I enter it always directs me to my "home" page?

Comment: Your form is POSTing to the home page because of `'url' => 'home'`...

Comment: Provide your user table structure. And perhaps one user from your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The action url should be `login`

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login' )) }}
                              ^^^^ as you used Auth::attempt to this URL

    {{ Form::label('username', 'Username: ') }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}
        </br>
    {{ Form::label('password', 'Password: ') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
        </br>
{{ Form::submit() }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```